# How to do a Cross Domain request using AJAX in chrome extension

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I am developing a chrome extension for facebook. I need to send data to another server (say `http://example.comxa.com`). I am using `XMLHttpRequest()` method for sending a `POST` request to the server.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","http://example.comxa.com",false);
xhr.send();
```

But I get the following error message in conosle:

```
Refused to connect to 'http://www.example.comxa.com/' because
 it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 
https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net
 http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* https://*.akamaihd.net
 ws://*.facebook.com:* http://*.akamaihd.net https://fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:
* *.atlassolutions.com http://attachment.fbsbx.com https://attachment.fbsbx.com".
```

and

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to 
connect to 'http://www.example.comxa.com/' because it violates the document's
 Content Security Policy.
```

I have already added permission for `http://www.example.comxa.com` in the manifest file :

```
"permissions": ["http://www.example.comxa.com/","storage"],
```

On searching I found that it is possible to make cross-origin AJAX requests in chrome extensions (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr), but how?

I also made an extension that used such a call to get meaning of selected word using AJAX but it worked fine:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
url = "http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/" + text +
 "?key=api-key";        
request.open("GET",url,true);
rewuest.send();
```

and  hadn't added permissions for `http://www.dictionaryapi.com/` in manifest.

Comment: Which script are you trying to connect from?

Comment: Or, more specifically, whether it's a content script.

Comment: Disregard my question, docs: _"Content scripts can also make cross-site XMLHttpRequests to the same sites as their parent extensions"_

Comment: @Xan Yes it is a content script.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @RobW Version 34.0.1847.137 m

Comment: `curl -X POST -d '' -vvv http://example.comxa.com` results in a redirect to `http://error404.000webhost.com/?`. If you add that permission, does the problem go away?

Comment: The actual site is not http://example.comxa.com. In the question I said assume (say) that its http://example.comxa.com.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your extension? @VivekKumar